# How to pass variable via $callback_args for add_meta_box

Tags: metabox, callbacks

I am trying to pass a variable to the callback function through `add_meta_box`. I know that there is `$callback_args` that can be used to pass the variable. But somehow I just can't get it to work within a class. This is my code:

```php
class myclass{
  //...blah blah...adding action
  function add_ex_field() {
    add_meta_box( 
      'apextadmin', 
      __( 'My Custom Field', 'myplugin_textdomain'),
      array($this,'the_callback_function'),
      post,
      //the $param is some value that is saved in my option table.
      array('test' => $param) 
    );
  }

  //do I need to include these two parameters? because they gave me error!
  function the_callback_function($post, $metabox){ 
    echo '<h1>testing field</h1>';
    echo $metabox['args']['test'];
   }
}
    
global $myclass; 
$myclass = new myclass();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes an example says more than a thousand words. Here's a small plugin that will guide you:

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#65981) »kaiser« Meta Box example
 * Plugin URI:  http://goo.gl/ls6Q6
 * Description: Example showing how to add a meta box with callback args
 * Author:      Franz Josef Kaiser
 * Author URI:  http://unserkaiser.com
 */

if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSE65981_MetaBox_Example' ) )
{
    add_action( 'load-post.php', array( 'WPSE65981_MetaBox_Example', 'init' ) );
    add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( 'WPSE65981_MetaBox_Example', 'init' ) );

/** 
 * The Class
 */
class WPSE65981_MetaBox_Example
{
    protected static $instance;

    public static function init()
    {
        null === self :: $instance AND self :: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_box' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Adds the meta box container
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_meta_box()
    {
        add_meta_box(
            // ID
             'wpse65981_meta_box_example'
            // Title/"hndle"-bar
            ,__( 'WPSE Meta Box Headline', 'example_textdomain' )
            // Callback
            ,array( $this, 'render_meta_box_content' )
            // post_type
            ,'post'
            // context
            ,'advanced'
            // priority
            ,'high'
            // callback_args
            ,array( 'Hello', "{$GLOBALS['current_user']->display_name}!" )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Render Meta Box content (Callback)
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function render_meta_box_content( $post, $callback_args ) 
    {
        // Argument dump: Uncomment for insights
        # var_dump( $post );
        # var_dump( $callback_args );

        $args = array_map( 'esc_html', $callback_args['args'] );
        return print "<h2>".implode( ' ', $args )."</h2>";
    }
} // END Class WPSE65981_MetaBox_Example

} // endif;
```

If you're wondering, how I identified those hooks that are used for the static `init` function to load, then [take a look at my »current admin info« plugin here](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info).

[image]

Comment: You don't need to use `&$this` in `add_(action|filter)` calls now that we don't have to support PHP4 anymore. Objects that are stored in variables aren't actually stored in variables -- it's an identifier that the caller (`call_user_func` in this case) uses to look up the object. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: @chrisguitarguy Yes, I know. Thanks for the "heads up". I just took the (old) Codex example and modified it to fit the question. As you can see from the edits, I just overlooked the first one :)

Comment: What if the variable that I want to pass is in an array? like this `foreach($options['rules'] as  $v){add_meta_box( 'pluginid', __( 'my plugin', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),array($this,'render_content'),$v['cpt'], array($v['variable']));}` ? This give me Illegal offset type. The options is stored in the wp_option table.

Comment: @t.ck Your way of adding the var is not correct. Define the array before and just add the variable. `$v['wrong'];` _vs._ just `$v`. If you need to extract some part before, just do `$n = $v['right'];`. If you need to define an array, then just do it, save it in a var and add this var then as argument.

Comment: I tried to define the var first like what you said.But I still get the error.

Comment: Okay, figured it out...turned out I need to defined all the args in add_meta_box() in order to make it works. I thought that using the default value of `$context` and `$priority` can do the job. Obviously I am wrong. However, Kaiser...thanks a lot.

Comment: The second arg inside the callback holds **all** meta box data. I just extracted the last part/the actual args in the callback. You can access context, etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is, just remember the arguments being passed on a subset of the original array.  While you are using a class structure, the basic non-class methodology still works.

So to pass an argument within the add_meta_box call, would be like this:

```
  $args = array('Index'=>'1');
  add_meta_box( 'mmd_listings_List_Group1',
           __( 'Title of Meta Box' ),
              'MyCallBack',
              'custom post name',
              'normal',
              'high',
               $args    <========== array with arguments
             );



 function MyCallBack($post_ID, $Arg)
  {
  $Index = $Arg['args']['Index'];   <=========== your argument in the function
  }
```

Check it out on:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/